# Error System.DllNotFoundException: fusion.dll on Azure storage using Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, azure-blob-storage, macos-sierra

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac, when I follow this guild.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

With code:

```
// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

I got this exception:

> System.DllNotFoundException: fusion.dll

I try to do in Visual Studio on Window, it is no problem. It is a problem of Visual Studio for Mac
Could you guide me how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I found another solution to get key "StorageConnectionString" from App.config file for Xamarin PCL project.

You need to install this package which support to get the value of key in App.config file: [PCLAppConfig](https://github.com/mrbrl/PCLAppConfig)

Then you can get the value by line code:

> string storageConnectionString =
>   PCLAppConfig.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

Answer (score 9):

> System.DllNotFoundException: fusion.dll

AFAIK, `Fusion.dll` is a type of DLL file associated with Microsoft .NET Framework for the Windows Operating System.  VS 2017 for Mac could build apps for mobile, web, and Xamarin and .NET Core,etc. I assumed that this issue caused by using the package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/).

[image]

Please try to use the latest version of [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and remove the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager package, then construct your `CloudStorageAccount` instance as follows to narrow this issue.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("the-value-of-your-storage-connectionstring");
```

Comment: Thank you! But this package, I cannot use App.Config file via method CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()

Comment: @TonyPham I am encountering the same exception when trying it on Mac. Did you find any solution? I am also trying to use the app.config.

Comment: @raringsunny As my above comment, I cannot use App.Config file. I declared a constant string variable to replace.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I did the same.

Answer (score 1):

In order user Azure webJobStorage Connection from local.settings.json file you can use

```
string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
```

Above line will read the value from local.settings.json file and replace with

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```